# Grails: create-controller not found?

Tags: grails

What could cause this error in grails 4 ? I'm using the CLI like this:

```
grails create-controller Book
```

Edit:

The exact error is

> | Error Command not found create-controller
>
> Did you mean: create-command or create-service or create-script?

Comment: Can you share a project which demonstrates that behavior?

Comment: Just an app with grails create-app --profile base I think.
Is there something that needs to be present in the gradle configuration for this to work?

Comment: I've added the error message, though I'm not sure it helps much.

Comment: You should not create a project with `--profile base`.

Comment: Why is that? Why is it available then? And in any case, what could cause create-controller command not to be available?

Comment: "Why is that? " - Because the project won't be configured in a useful way.  "Why is it available then?" - More involved than will fit in a comment here, but in short, it has to do with how our cli and profile system works. "what could cause create-controller command not to be available" - Your project wont' have the necessary dependency to pull in the `create-controller` command.

Comment: If you look in your `build.gradle` file, you will see it isn't pulling in `org.grails:grails-core` but isn't pulling in any web stuff.

Comment: So what are the necessary dependencies to pull in the create-controller command, and what command to use to create an app?

Comment: "what command to use to create an app" - The usual thing is `grails create-app appname`.  That will create a project configured with the `web` profile.  If you wanted to build a REST api without a browser front end, you might use `grails create-app --profile rest-api appname`.  You specify whatever profile helps you build the kind of app you want.  `base` isn't a profile that helps you build an app that contains controllers.

Comment: You can also use https://start.grails.org/ to create the app.

Comment: And since it's now already created, can you please give me the changes I need to apply to build.gradle to make sure that command is available?

Comment: The simplest thing is to `grails create-app appname` and copy the dependencies from that `build.gradle` into yours.

Comment: I don't really see any significant differences with my build.gradle and the build.gradle generated with --profile rest-api. Would you mind telling me what's the exact dependency I should have to make create-controller available?

Comment: "I don't really see any significant differences with my build.gradle and the build.gradle generated with --profile rest-api." - Then your `build.gradle` was not created with `--profile base`.  There are a lot of significant differences.  See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/8070991bf1ecef0342394fc7d2b0ee36

Comment: I actually didn't create it so I don't really know (I stated "I think" in my first comment). Maybe it was created with the rest-api profile then. Sorry I influenced your judgment. However, is it not possible to find out, in the rest-api profile, what's the line that's supposed to enable this create-controller command?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Can you please help me? I still haven't figured out what's wrong...

Comment: Without seeing the project it is hard to say what is wrong.  It isn't clear to me why you can't create a project and use that build file as a starting point.  I am sorry I can't help.  Best of luck.

Comment: Just to be clear, I did try replacing my build.gradle with the one from grails create-app --profile rest-api project, but the error is still the same. Whether I use grails from system, or grailsw from the project. And it's still present in 4.0.0. Any pointers on how I could try to debug this?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I've found out what was wrong, thx for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In grails-app/conf/application.yml, the profile has to be rest-api (or similar) instead of base for the command to be available.

Comment: Right.  There is really no good reason to create an app with the `base` profile.